# Which Timeseries Database would be more suitable for Sensor Datas - InfluxDb or Prometheus

Tags: time-series, devops, prometheus, influxdb, data-handling

I have searched for it in many blogs, but it seems all the blogs present a biased view. I myself am having a little bias towards Prometheus now, However, i did not find any good article which explains a use case of Prometheus for sensor data.

In my case, we manufacture IoT devices and we have a lot of data coming in. Till now we have been using MongoDB for everything, but now I want to switch to a time-series database, but I am really confused, whether I can choose Prometheus or not.

I am comfortable writing my own metric converter which can convert my sensor data into Prometheus metrics format (If something doesn't exist already)

Comment: Are the IoT devices deployed in a challenging environment (bad internet connection, no out-of-the-box way for the Prometheus server to access ports / http endpoints on the devices etc)? Prometheus follows the push model after all and requires you to expose an endpoint on every target (there is the push gateway but it is not made for this)

Comment: You could also ask on the Prometheus community mailing list if anyone has experience with IoT devices (at scale). Nevertheless, my gut tells me that a simple push model is more appropriate

Answer (score 2):

I think i found it. Its [Victoria Metrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics). Haven't seen something as amazing as VM. First thing, it supports both Prometheus and Influx DB Write protocol(not just these, it supports some other time series database protocols also) and supports query language similar to prometheus.  It has Vm Agent whose multiple instances we can run easily. It has cluster support and performance-wise, nothing like it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't feel bd, lots of folks start out trying MongoDB for IoT applications because Mongo claims it's great for IoT. Only problem is, it's terrible for IoT. :-)

What you need is a true Time Series Database (TSDB). If you want to be able to query your data with SQL, try out [QuestDB](https://questdb.io/?ref=davidgsiot). It's the fastest open source TSDB out there and it's small.